# One FTDI on Three Atmega

Tags: usb, uart, ftdi

I'm doing a schematic for an arduino project-based and I can not proceed. I'm facing a problem which I have no idea how can I solve it so that's the reason I'm writing back to you.

The thing is: I have three atmega 328 and I want to program them using a single ftdi or a USB-UART converter. I can not put the chip outside the board and program them one by one, so the ftdi should be in the PCB.
I was wondering if I can do it using a switch with three positions with the help of 3 MOSFETs but I found it impossible, is it? Do you have any idea how can I solve this clue?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered putting in 6-pin programming headers and using a programmer and a program like avrdude?

Comment: Sounds like you are talking to serial bootloaders, so you need to both block data input to the wrong ones, and only connect data output from the right one.  You could indeed do that with MOSFET pass gates, discrete or integrated.  Ultimate simplicity would be jumper blocks.  You could probably also come up with a clean software solution using a 16u2 instead of FTDI and soft serial to the targets - see the firmware source for the one on the Uno.

Comment: I want to use a usb as an external socket so the ftdi must be in the board.
I want to provide a plug and play solution so the user just need to plug an usb cable to upload new firmware for each microcontroller.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how I can solve this clue just using Mosfets?

Comment: Doesnt the ftdi chip just facilitate programming via JTAG?

Comment: @JonRB  No, the FTDI chip doesn't facilitate programming through JTAG.  (It seems to me that you've got some reading about AVR and Arduino to do.)

Comment: This is off topic as it is an EE design problem, not an arduino question.  It belongs on EESE where it was properly asked.